# Use an enum with a function which has a slice parameter

Tags: rust

I use an enum to choose between different function signatures. As long as the function has "normal" (sized) parameters, like `u8`, this works fine. But as soon as I use a function with a slice as parameter, I get compiler errors. I found a workaround, but I am not sure if this is the only way to solve this. And I don't understand why. Assuming the function is stored as a pointer, how do the parameters change what is possible?

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone/*, Debug, Eq, PartialEq*/)]
pub enum Function {
    FunctionVal(fn(u8) -> String),
    //FunctionSlice(fn(&[u8]) -> String), // E0277
    FunctionSlice(&'static fn(&[u8]) -> String), // workaround
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone/*, Debug, Eq, PartialEq*/)]
pub struct FunctionStruct {
    pub func: Function,
}

pub static FUNC1: FunctionStruct = FunctionStruct {
    func: Function::FunctionVal(convert_u8_to_string),
};

static F2:fn(&[u8]) -> String = convert_u8slice_to_string;
pub static FUNC2: FunctionStruct = FunctionStruct {
    func: Function::FunctionSlice(&F2), // to avoid E0308
};

fn convert_u8_to_string(_:u8) -> String { String::from("") }
fn convert_u8slice_to_string(_:&[u8]) -> String { String::from("") }

fn main() {
    let f = FUNC1;

    match f.func {
        Function::FunctionVal(f) => { f(0); }
        Function::FunctionSlice(f) => { f(&[0u8]); }
    }
}
```

[(Rust Playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0649605edfc82e9f0f1bf0e259bcfebf&version=stable&backtrace=0)

As soon as there is a slice as parameter, `#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]` is not possible any more. But that is not a problem in my case.

I was not able to make `FunctionSlice(fn(&[u8]) -> String),` work. I had to use a reference type with a static lifetime. Otherwise `#[derive(Copy, Clone)]` would fail. To initialize the struct, I had to use an additional static.

I am currently using rust 1.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to [issue 28229](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28229): some types implement `Copy` but not `Clone` (even though `Copy` is a subtrait of `Clone`, so this should be impossible!). This means that you *can* derive `Copy` but you *cannot* derive `Clone`. It's possible to work around this by implementing `Clone` manually by copying `self`.

```
#[derive(Copy)]
pub enum Function {
    FunctionVal(fn(u8) -> String),
    FunctionSlice(fn(&[u8]) -> String),
}

impl Clone for Function {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        *self
    }
}
```

This does not help with deriving `Debug` and `PartialEq`, though. You'll only be able to do that when an implementation for the respective trait is added to the problematic type. In the meantime, you'll have to implement them by yourself. (`Eq` can be derived if `PartialEq` is provided.)

[For example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=60b227f3a0b088006764ed45cc3851b9&version=stable&backtrace=0):

```
impl PartialEq for Function {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Function) -> bool {
        match (self, other) {
            (&Function::FunctionVal(a), &Function::FunctionVal(b)) => a == b,
            (&Function::FunctionSlice(a), &Function::FunctionSlice(b)) => a as usize == b as usize,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
}

impl fmt::Debug for Function {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            &Function::FunctionVal(ref p) => {
                try!(f.write_str("FunctionVal:"));
                fmt::Pointer::fmt(p, f)
            },
            &Function::FunctionSlice(ref p) => {
                try!(f.write_str("FunctionSlice:"));
                fmt::Pointer::fmt(&(*p as *const ()), f)
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the implementations of `PartialEq` and `Debug`, because I did need them now. (For my unittests). Your answer also helped me fix that!